# JavaScript REPL in skewer-mode

Tags: skewer-mode

I'm using skewer-mode and can't use the `skewer-repl`, which is unfortunate.
I get a prompt

> js>

then I can enter anything, nothing is happening...
`js-REPL:run` and `Shell-Compile` are running as major modes in the skewer-repl.
I'm using Emacs 24.5 on Mac OSX
Any idea how I can make it working? Thanks